observeEvent to reset a reactiveVal DF to empty after each click
Here's the situation:
I am building an app that populates a chart after some inputs are selected and an actionButton is clicked.  However, the behavior I was expecting is that each time you click the button, it overwrites the old chart.  Instead, I noticed that it seems to retain the values even after the button is clicked with new inputs.
To reproduce this, consider the code below.  If you select all values (A,B,C,D,E) and press calculate, you get a chart output.  However, if you then clear the outputs and select say, just (A,C,E), you still get results/lines for (B,D), even though they were not selected in the second click action.  I would like to clear out the df2() data frame on each click and chart only the items that were selected at that time.
Any advice is much appreciated.

library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

################################################################################
## UI code
################################################################################

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Select 
  ################################################################################ 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Selector
      selectInput("input1", 
                  label = h4("Choose an item"), 
                  choices = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selectize = TRUE),
      
      # Action Buttons
      fluidRow(
        # Calculate 
        actionButton("calc", label = "Calculate")
        )
      ),
      
      
      mainPanel(
        
        plotlyOutput("plot",height=400)
        
      ) 
    ) 
  )

  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    df2 = reactiveVal(
      data.frame(
        symbol = character(0),
        metric = numeric(0)
      )
    )
    
    df3 = reactiveVal(
      data.frame(
        symbol = character(0),
        metric = numeric(0)
      )
    )
    
    
    observeEvent(input$calc, {
      
      df1 = data.frame(symbol = input$input1)
      
      # Create table for the time series plot
      plot_tbl = cbind(
        df1,data.frame(x=sample.int(100, length(input$input1)), y=sample.int(100, length(input$input1)))
      )
      
      df2(dplyr::bind_rows(df2(), plot_tbl))
      
    })
    
    
    output$plot = renderPlotly({
      
      
      ggplotly(
        ggplot(data = df2()) +
          geom_line(aes(x, y, color = symbol), size = 1, alpha = .9)
      )
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


One option to fix your issue would be to initalize or (re-initalize) df2()  as an empty data frame inside the observeEvent:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("input1",
        label = h4("Choose an item"),
        choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selectize = TRUE
      ),
      fluidRow(
        actionButton("calc", label = "Calculate")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("plot", height = 400)
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df2 <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$calc, {
    # Re-Init df2
    df2(
      data.frame(
        symbol = character(0),
        metric = numeric(0)
      )
    )
    
    plot_tbl <- data.frame(
      symbol = input$input1,
      x = sample.int(100, length(input$input1)),
      y = sample.int(100, length(input$input1))
    )

    df2(dplyr::bind_rows(df2(), plot_tbl))
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(df2())
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(data = df2()) +
        geom_point(aes(x, y, color = symbol), size = 1, alpha = .9)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

